# A meta-regression with effect sizes from variously designed studies

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am performing a meta-regression using various types of effect size from two independent samples design study; pre- and post-test for one sample design study; and frequency comparison design study and so on.

Can I include all those various types of effect size into one meta-regression?

Answer (score 1):

If you can convert them all onto a common scale then the answer is yes, otherwise no. If you do do this then include as one of your moderators a factor with levels corresponding to different study designs to check if the difference makes a difference.